# R data management: Aggregating multiple variables into newly generated variable based on multiple conditions from other variables

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I'm a brand New R user, this is my first attempt at conditional statements - and first time posting an online question - so please bear with me.

I'm managing data from a questionnaire survey into something that can be analyzed. As a rookie mistake, I've been using the question form "tick all that apply" frequently - obtaining a matrix with one column per alternative answer. I am trying to combine these by conditional logic into a single column per question.

Using one of these matrices as example, my dataframe BS looks like this:

```
ID Q29_ Q29_ Q29_3 Q29_4
1  1    NA    NA    1
2  NA   1     1     1 
3  1    NA    NA    NA 
4  NA   1    NA    NA
[…]
```

Using following code

```
  BS1 <- BS %>%
  mutate(WaterOutdoors = c("", "Yes")[(Q29_2 %in% c("Outdoors") | 
                                     Q29_3 == "Outdoors" |
                                     Q29_4 == "Outdoors")+1])
```

I get

```
ID Q29_ Q29_ Q29_3 Q29_4 WaterOutdoors
1  1    NA   NA     1          Yes
2  NA   1     1     1          Yes
3  1   NA    NA    NA          
4  NA  NA    NA    NA
5  NA   1    NA    NA         Yes
[…]
```

I would like to add a "No"-option to the "WaterOutdoors" variable for those rows who have ticked off Q29_1 (Q29_1="1") and *did not* tick of any of the following (Q29_2=NA, Q29_3=NA, Q29_4=NA), and at *the same time* leave "WaterOutdoors" either empty or NA if *none* of the Q29_1:_4 have been ticked of.

I have tried

```
BS1$WaterOutdoors <- with(BS1, ifelse(Q29_1 %>% c("InStable") & 
                                    is.na(Q29_2) &
                                    is.na(Q29_3) &
                                    is.na(Q29_4),
                                  "No",""))
```

hoping to get

```
ID Q29_ Q29_ Q29_3 Q29_4 WaterOutdoors
1  1    NA   NA     1          Yes
2  NA   1    1      1          Yes
3  1    NA   NA     NA         No
4  NA   NA   NA     NA         NA
5  NA   1    NA     NA         Yes
[…]
```

but rather got the error-message: "Error in Q29_1 %>% c("InStable") & is.na(Q29_2) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types"

My logic is obviously flawed, any input on how I *should* have gone about doing this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is always the case, there are many possible solutions.  Here's one using only base code.

```
## Recreating your dataset
df <- data.frame(
  Q29_1 = as.integer(c(1, NA, 1, NA, NA)),
  Q29_2 = as.integer(c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 1)),
  Q29_3 = as.integer(c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA)),
  Q29_4 = as.integer(c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

## Convert all NAs to 0
df[is.na(df)] <- 0

## Concatenate all answers into a string
df$WaterOutdoors <- as.character(paste0(df$Q29_1, df$Q29_2, df$Q29_3, df$Q29_4))

## Recode
df$WaterOutdoors <- as.character(
  ## If first value is 1 and all rest are 0, meaning 1000 then "No"
  ifelse(df$WaterOutdoors == "1000", "No", 
         ## If the substring of 2-4 contains a 1 then "Yes"
         ifelse(grepl("1", substr(df$WaterOutdoors, 2, 4)), "Yes", 
                ## Else NA (could also have said if else df$WaterOutdoors == "0000")
                as.character(NA))
         ))

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not completely understand the code, but based on what you explained,  it could be achieved using `case_when` from `dplyr` package.

`case_when` function will add an `NA` when any of the conditions is met. In this case if all variables are `NA`

```r
library(dplyr)

Q29_1 <- c(1, NA, 1, NA)
Q29_2 <- c(NA, 1, NA, 1)
Q29_3 <- c(NA, 1, NA, NA)
Q29_4 <- c(1, 1, NA, NA)

BS <- data.frame(Q29_1 = Q29_1,
                 Q29_2 = Q29_2,
                 Q29_3 = Q29_3,
                 Q29_4 = Q29_4)

BS1 <- BS %>%
  mutate(WaterOutdoors = case_when(rowSums(.[,c("Q29_2", "Q29_3", "Q29_4")], na.rm = TRUE) > 0 ~ "Yes",
                                   Q29_1 == 1 & rowSums(.[,c("Q29_2", "Q29_3", "Q29_4")], na.rm = TRUE) == 0 ~ "No"))
```